# QR factorization for ridge regression

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, regression

I am solving an overdetermined system of equations:
$$Ax= b$$

Using QR factorization, we can solve this system easily by posing it as:

$$Rx= Q'b$$

I would like to regularize my estimate of $x$. I can use ridge regression with the normal equations being:

$$(A'A+\lambda\Gamma'\Gamma)x=A'b$$

My question is, how can I directly transform $A$ to matrix $\Delta$ such that solving the system $\Delta x=b$ via QR factorization yields the regularized estimate for $x$.

Comment: What do you mean "directly transform $A$ to $\Delta$"? The relation is $\Delta=A'A+ \lambda \Gamma' \Gamma$. Do you mean how to obtain the QR factorization of $\Delta$ from that of $A$?

Comment: I voted you up here as you gave a name to my own personal "discovery" and can now study some literature on the subject. That being said, I am not sure that I understand your question. But I write an answer I think helps...

Comment: Yes I meant QR factorization of $\Delta$ from $A$. Poster Adam W has guided me in the correct direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try writing it as (using $\lambda = 1$ for display simplicity)
$$B = \pmatrix{ A \\ \Gamma}$$
then you have for the equation $Bx = \pmatrix{b \\ 0}$

\begin{align}
  B'Bx &= B' \pmatrix{b \\ 0} \\
  \pmatrix{ A' & \Gamma'}\pmatrix{ A \\ \Gamma}x &= \pmatrix{ A' & \Gamma'} \pmatrix{b \\ 0} \\
  (A'A + \Gamma'\Gamma)x &= A'b 
\end{align}

Therefore in terms of the QR factorization, take the QR factors of $$B = \pmatrix{ A \\ \Gamma}$$